# How can I svn:ingnore all local svn:externals changes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a local copy of a SVN project with many externals. I would like to change some of the externals on my local copy and ignore them forever so I don't commit them accidentally.

How can I ignore external changes for my local copy?

I'd like something equivalent to `svn propset svn:ignore "svn:externals"`